# Grouping related records of ArrayList and putting into HashMap using java

Tags: java

I am having a group of records in ArrayList with fields "recordID", "refNo" and "baseRefNo". "baseRefNo" is related with "refNo" of another "recordID".  I need to group the related records and put it into HashMap. Here is basic overview of my code.

```
import java.util.*;
class RecordLog {
    String recordID;
    String refNo;
    String baseRefNo;

    RecordLog(String recordID, String refNo, String baseRefNo) {
      this.recordID = recordID;
      this.refNo = refNo;
      this.baseRefNo = baseRefNo;
     }
  } 

  public class HelloWorld{
      public static void main(String []args){
       List<RecordLog> logList = new ArrayList<RecordLog>();
       Map<String, List<RecordLog>> recordLogMap = new HashMap<String, List<RecordLog>>();
       RecordLog record1 = new RecordLog("1","A","B");
       RecordLog record2 = new RecordLog("2","B","C");
       RecordLog record3 = new RecordLog("3","C","");
       RecordLog record4 = new RecordLog("4","D","");
       RecordLog record5 = new RecordLog("5","E","");
       logList.add(record1);
       logList.add(record2);
       logList.add(record3);
       logList.add(record4);
       logList.add(record5);

       //need to group related records and put into HashMap
       List<RecordLog> refNoALogList = new ArrayList<RecordLog>();
       refNoALogList.add(record1);
       refNoALogList.add(record2);
       refNoALogList.add(record3);

       List<RecordLog> refNoBLogList = new ArrayList<RecordLog>();
       refNoBLogList.add(record4);

       List<RecordLog> refNoCLogList = new ArrayList<RecordLog>();
       refNoCLogList.add(record5);

       recordLogMap.put("A",refNoALogList); 
       recordLogMap.put("D", refNoBLogList);
       recordLogMap.put("E", refNoCLogList );

      }

    }

Could you please suggest an idea as how this can be done or is there any other way to handle this

Thank You
```

Comment: sorry to confuse,  above code is just an attempt as how I wanted to be.    Assuming that I am having arrayList named "LogList" I need to group related records of "LogList" and need to put into map named "recordLogMap".  Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package com.inlet.ifserver;

import java.util.*;
class RecordLog {
    String recordID;
    String refNo;
    String baseRefNo;
    RecordLog parent;
    RecordLog child;

    RecordLog(String recordID, String refNo, String baseRefNo) {
        this.recordID = recordID;
        this.refNo = refNo;
        this.baseRefNo = baseRefNo;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){
        List<RecordLog> logList = new ArrayList<RecordLog>();
        Map<String, List<RecordLog>> recordLogMap = new HashMap<String, List<RecordLog>>();
        RecordLog record1 = new RecordLog("1","A","B");
        RecordLog record2 = new RecordLog("2","B","C");
        RecordLog record3 = new RecordLog("3","C","");
        RecordLog record4 = new RecordLog("4","D","");
        RecordLog record5 = new RecordLog("5","E","");
        logList.add(record1);
        logList.add(record2);
        logList.add(record3);
        logList.add(record4);
        logList.add(record5);

        // First, make an index for easy look up of each record by refNo
        Map<String, RecordLog> index = new HashMap<>();
        for (RecordLog rec : logList)
            index.put(rec.refNo, rec);

        // Now doubly link the records into a set of linked lists
        for (RecordLog rec : logList)
            if (rec.baseRefNo.length() > 0) {
                RecordLog parent = index.get(rec.baseRefNo);
                parent.child = rec;
                rec.parent = parent;
            }

        // Now, find the top of each linked list by processing the records without children. Walk
        // the parent links to build each list of records in a chain.  Once the chain's list is built,
        // record it in recordLogMap
        for (RecordLog rec : logList)
            if (rec.child == null) {
                List<RecordLog> records = new ArrayList<>();
                records.add(rec);
                RecordLog p = rec;
                while (p.parent != null) {
                    records.add(p.parent);
                    p = p.parent;
                }
                recordLogMap.put(rec.refNo, records);
            }

        // Now print the results
        for (String refNo : recordLogMap.keySet()) {
            List<RecordLog> records = recordLogMap.get(refNo);
            System.out.println(refNo);
            for (RecordLog rec : records)
                System.out.println(String.format("  %s", rec.refNo));
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
A
  A
  B
  C
D
  D
E
  E
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much  Steve.  I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: No problem.  I like challenges like this.  Note that if you didn't want to touch the original data structures, you could build a separate linked list structure from another set of records.  But it's simpler and more direct to just use the records you already have by adding 'parent' and 'child' links to them.  Glad I could be of some help while having some nerdy fun!

Comment: Also note that you could store the other end of each chain in the final map and build the lists in reverse order by looking for nodes with no parents and then walking the child links rather than what was done, which is to look for nodes with no children and then walk the parent links.

Comment: Very nice!  I was going to attempt this, but Steve's solution is just fine.

Comment: Dear Steve, I noted your suggestions.  Your code helped me to save lot of my time.  Thank You